# How can I skip the permissions dialog for Facebook's iOS single sign on?

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, single-sign-on

I have an iPad application that requires users to log in to Facebook. I've implemented this using the iOS SDK that Facebook supplies, but I'm hitting a snag for returning users. Here are the steps they take:

- The user loads our app for the first time.
- They click 'login', which redirects them to the Facebook iPad app if they have it installed.
- They see a permissions dialog, which they accept.
- They sign out of our app and close it.
- At a later date, they reopen our app.
- They click on 'login' within our app.
- That takes them to the Facebook iPad app, which gives the empty permissions dialog shown below, since they've already authorized us and granted us full permissions.

The problem is that we're seeing confused users, because the call to action ('Okay') is buried in the top left of the title bar, and the messaging is unclear. In our testing, the Flipboard app displays the dialog briefly in this situation, but it is closed automatically and control is returned to the calling app. This is what we'd like to happen in our case too, but it's unclear how to achieve that. Here's a few things I've tried so far that haven't solved the problem:

- Updated to the latest Facebook iOS SDK at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk
- Passing nil or an empty array to [Facebook authorize]
- Searched the documentation (and the web) for any relevant leads
- Inspected the SDK code for any undocumented parameters

Does anybody have suggestions on how to skip this repeated authorization dialog on a repeat visit? Any help much appreciated.

[image: iPad screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Once we were able to get app store approval and release, we found that updating the SSO details with the Apple bundle id made the dialog behave as expected.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem now too. How did you get the behavior of auto redirecting back to your app from the FB app if the user has already authorized?

Answer (score 0):

This was demonstrated in [Facebook's iOS API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/), specifically, step 4 of "Modify the application delegate header file"

```
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil]; // this is what displays the facebook dialog
}
```

The `isSessionValid` checks if a valid cookie exists and if it does, then you don't need to `authorize` again.

**Edit:**

It occured to me that if your users don't use your app for a long time, then your cookie will be expired anyway. In that case then I'm not sure we can do anything about it, because FB's (re)authentication relies on that dialog.

Comment: This is what we do. The problem is that the second time this happens, the dialog shown above appears, and it's confusing, especially for a user who's already given permission. Other apps (eg Flipboard) are able to skip this dialog on subsequent attempts, which is what we're attempting to do.

Comment: Are you sure the app is not clearing cookies? Our apps skip this dialog just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the session information as described in Step 6 and read in Step 3 of [IOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)?

If so, if you'll have to start extending the token:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token

This is relatively new now that `offline_access` is deprecated.